# a function that takes an array A and index i and rearrange it

Tags: c++, arrays

Question is: *write a function that takes an array A of length n and an index i into A, and rearrange the elments such that all elements less than A[i] appear first, followed by elements equal to A[i], followed by elements greater than A[i].*

explanation for my code:

Ask user for n numbers, which is 11. And ask him what the index that he wants to rearrange the elements with. It takes it to function1, and creates a for loop and does an if else statement. if A[i] < A{index} , place it in the begining, else if it's less, place it at the end, or place it in the middle:

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function1(int a[], int ind);
int main()

{
    int a[11];
    int index;
    cout << " enter the numbers: " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < 11; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    cout << "what is the index ? " << endl;
    cin >> index;

    function1(a,index);
}

void function1(int a[], int ind)
{
    int x = a[ind];
    int newArray[11];
    for(int i=0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] < x)
        {
            newArray[i] = a[i];
        }
        else if(a[i] > x)
        {
            newArray[10-i] = a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            newArray[10/2] = a[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
        cout << newArray[i] << " ";
}
```

The output that I am expecting to get is the rearrangement of the new array which will probably look similar to this:

a[0....x....n-1], where x is the index that represents a[i]
however I am getting incorrect output with numbers randomly scattered across

what is wrong with my logic ?

Comment: What precisely _"doesn't` work"_? Edit your question please to improve about this. You are familiar with the concept of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here I suppose?

Comment: I edited the question. I am not getting the output that I am expecting to get, which is  [ 0........a[index].......n-1]  in an ascending order

Comment: You still didn't got it! Which particular input, expected output, debugged anomalies? You narrow your code down to a minimal test-case anyone could easily reproduce at e.g. Ideone.

Comment: I think the problem is you have not read the question to know what output I am expecting.  the debug anomalies are not known which is one of the reasons why I am here. The input could be any numbers and any index. the problem is not in the input !

Comment: The problem merely is you didn't read the link I gave in my 1st comment. I well have read your question, but I'm not willing to debug your code under these conditions (which you obviously missed to do yourself).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my question it is crystal clear. wouldn't have gotten the answers I needed below if it was not. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73007/discussion-between-mozein-and--).

Comment: just a tip, you can avoid may problems by using `std::vector` instead of raw pointers and `new`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The question specifically needs me to use an array. Thanks

Comment: @Mozein: Are you sure. `std::vector` is an array.

Comment: @Mozein FWIW, the solution to your problem is actually a one-liner:  `std::stable_partition(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int n) {return n < a[index];});`

Comment: Actually, a three line function using `sort` and `stable_partition`:  http://ideone.com/78DgoD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that (like Olaf Dietsche pointed out) you take just one index where two are necessary. Further you can't know if the element that is neither smaller not bigger than `a[ind]` (means equal to `a[ind]`) is to be inserted in the middle of the new array. (Imagine `3 2 1` and index 3 results in `2 1 3` but 3 isn't in the middle!)

**Updated Version** (allows for multiple elements with same value as pivot element)

```
void rearange(int* data, int size, int pivot)
{
    int* temp_data = new int[size];
    int start_index = 0, end_index = size - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] < data[pivot]) // -> insert 'before' pivot element
        {
            temp_data[start_index] = data[i];
            start_index++;
        }
        else if (data[i] > data[pivot]) // -> insert 'behind' pivot element
        {
            temp_data[end_index] = data[i];
            endIndex--;
        }
        // else: skip pivot(s)
    }

    // insert pivot element(s)
    for (int i = start_index; i <= end_index; i++)
    {
        temp_data[i] = data[pivot];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << temp_data[i] << " ";
    }
    delete[] temp_data;
}
```

Input:

```
11 10 9 8 7 7 7 6 5 4 3
5
```

Output

```
6 5 4 3 7 7 7 8 9 10 11
```

As you see, all elements smaller than element 5 (with value of 7) are before, all elements greater are behind the pivot element. All other elements with same value as pivot are wrapped around position 5, wherever there's free space. However the rearranged elements are not yet sorted (apart from being positioned relative to pivot element)!

Comment: What if there are multiple numbers that equals to a[ind] ? @xmoex

Comment: i've updated the answer and made it independent from hardcoded size

Answer (score 1):

You use the same index `i` for the smaller and larger values. This means, if only the last value `a[10]` is larger than `x`, you will write it in the first location `newArray[10 - 10]`, even though you already filled all places up to the 10th. Another problem is, when you have multiple `middle` values. They will all be stored into `newArray[5]`.

What you want to achieve is called partitioning, as used in the [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm.

You need to maintain two indexes (pointers), one for the smaller (left) and one for the larger (right) values.

Comment: that makes it an o(n^2) which I am trying to stay away from, is there any linear solutions ?

Comment: Why do you think this is O(n^2)?

Comment: I thought two indexes pointers needs two for loops. Was proven wrong by @xmoex anwser. I gave you a vote up for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine the size of your array at the beginning and pass the fixed size of the array to the function as a parameter.